# How to use Jest to mock Algolia's connectors?

Tags: mocking, jestjs, algolia

I am using [`jest`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions) to write tests of my [React Native Algolia Search](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/state-results/react/?language=react#connector) components.

A (very stripped back) `NoResults` component:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { connectStateResults } from 'react-instantsearch-native'

const NoResults = ({ searching, searchState: { query } }) => searching || !query ? null : (
  <View>
    <Text>No Results</Text>
  </View>
)

export default connectStateResults(NoResults)
```

in `<projectRoot>/__mocks__/react-instantsearch-native.js`

```js
module.exports = jest.genMockFromModule('react-instantsearch-native')
```

And my test

```js
import 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'

import * as risn from 'react-instantsearch-native'

import NoResults from './NoResults'

jest.mock('react-instantsearch-native')

it('renders correctly', () => {
  risn.connectStateResults.mockImplementation(comp => comp({ searching: true, searchState: { query: '' } }))

  const tree = renderer.create(<NoResults />).toJSON()
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

What I find is that `connectStateResults` never returns anything.

```
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

  19 |   })
  20 | 
> 21 |   const tree = renderer.create(<NoResults />).toJSON()
```

I've checked and the mock is definitely being loaded and used, but it's being used before the `mockImplementation` function is set.

How do I correctly mock Algolia's connectors?

**Update**

Algolia support suggested I change the line

```js
risn.connectStateResults.mockImplementation(comp => comp({ searching: true, searchState: { query: '' } }))
```

to

```js
risn.connectStateResults.mockImplementation(comp => () => comp({ searching: true, searchState: { query: '' } }))
```

but that made no difference

Answer (score 0):

I worked this out as follows:

The issue is that in the `NoResult` component the `connectStateResults` is being executed after the mock is loaded (correctly) but before the `mockImplementation` is invoked, because it's invoked when `NoResult` is first imported.

The solution is actually trivial.

Instead of a complex `mockImplementation` call in the test, I set up `mockImplementation` in my mock `<projectRoot>/__mocks__/react-instantsearch-native.js` and just set the implementation to be a simple identity function `const a => a`

```js
const i = a => a

const risn = jest.genMockFromModule('react-instantsearch-native')

risn.connectStateResults.mockImplementation(i)

module.exports = risn
```

Then my test becomes

```js
import 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'

import NoResults from './NoResults'

jest.mock('react-instantsearch-native')

it('renders correctly when searching', () => {
  const tree = renderer
    .create(<NoResults searching searchState={{ query: '' }} />)
    .toJSON()
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

This works perfectly and can easily be extended to cover any other components that use Algolia's connectors.